# Is there a comprehensive list of all Linq Statements?

Tags: linq

I would like to have a list of all Linq Staments (Methods and Queryies)
I have googled for a while but with no results.
So is there a list with all LinQ statements somewhere? It doesn't even need explanations, just all the features listed.

Comment: Not sure if there's a cheat sheet for LINQ.  But there's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/standard-query-operators-overview) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Microsoft documentation [Standard Query Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/standard-query-operators-overview#related-sections)